# how to call python 3.5 async function in a celery task?

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

i have an async function in python 3.5 like this:

```
async def get_pool():
    if Cache.__current:
        return Cache.__current

    Cache.__current = await aioredis.create_redis_pool(
        (settings.CACHE_SETTINGS['SERVER'], settings.CACHE_SETTINGS['PORT']),
        minsize=settings.CACHE_SETTINGS['MIN_SIZE'],
        maxsize=settings.CACHE_SETTINGS['MAX_SIZE'])

    return Cache.__current
```

and a celery Periodic Task that call the async get_pool() function and  it performs operations on its data:

```
@app.task
def check_data_task():
    cache = Cache.get_pool()
    ...
```

as expected This codes gives an error:

```
("'coroutine' object has no attribute XXX method'")
```

and Now is the time to ask questions:

1. this is a good idea to use python async function in a celery task? if yes then:
2. how to use a python coroutine function in a celery task?

Answer (score 0):

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

async def get_pool():
    if Cache.__current:
    ....

@app.task
def check_data_task():
    ...
    async_to_sync(get_poll)
```